# How does Facebook's React JSX transformer work?

Tags: javascript, xml, facebook, reactjs

How is it even possible that React allows you to write JSX (XML) within javascript without it throwing any errors? I have been trying to wrap my head around it, and I am not quite sure how the underlying code accomplishes this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple, it looks for `<script type="text/jsx">` tags, parses them, generates the corresponding javascript code, and `eval`'s  it.

This is why the `jsx` inline transformer should be used only when developing, as having to parse the `jsx` code decreases the performance of your web page. When deploying, you should convert all `jsx` code into `js` one before deploy.

Comment: @Cristik - just to understand. the xml is still there, it should fail anyway. isn't it?

Comment: @yossi even if the xml would be still there, the browser wouldn't know how to interpret it, so if will just skip it.